# Translate resilience4j @TimeLimiter annotation to code

Tags: annotations, resilience4j, time-limiting

What does the `@TimeLimiter` annotation exactly?

#### Example

```
    @TimeLimiter(name = "abc123")
    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> execute(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier);
    }
```

Could be equal to:

```
    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> execute(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        TimeLimiter timeLimiter = timeLimiterRegistry.timeLimiter("abc123");

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3); // This scheduler must somehow exist with the annotation as well right?
        return timeLimiter.executeCompletionStage(
            scheduler, () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier)).toCompletableFuture();
    }
```

The scheduler required in the non-blocking variant of the code, is that somehow involved in the annotation?

#### Research

I've mainly read:

1. Resilience4J's [Guide on TimeLimiter](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/timeout)
2. Reflectoring's blog post [Implementing Timeouts with Resilience4j](https://reflectoring.io/time-limiting-with-resilience4j/)

Is there some other place where I can understand what the annotation does?

Answer (score 1):

The annotation is collected by an annotation-processor like in `resilience4j-spring` the [`TimeLimiterAspect`](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/timelimiter/configure/TimeLimiterAspect.java).

Here Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) extension [*AspectJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) is used to create an *Advice* for the time-limiting resilience *Aspect* around the *JointPoint* of the annotated method.

You can look at its [code, e.g. line 90](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/timelimiter/configure/TimeLimiterAspect.java#L90) to figure out, how the evaluated annotation and method/class meta-information is used to *weave* (Advice) the `TimeLimiter` decoration (Aspect) around the annotated method's execution (JointPoint).

#### Further reading

For an introduction to AOP with AspectJ you can read Baeldung's [Intro to AspectJ](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) .

How Resilience4J leverages AOP can be read in official Resilience4J Guides,  **Spring Boot 2**, [Getting started with resilience4j-spring-boot2, Annotations](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#annotations):

> The Spring Boot2 starter provides annotations and AOP Aspects which are auto-configured.